Would it be technically correct to call stratospheric aerosol injection "chemtrails"?
There is a BBC article about geo-engineering being the subject of conspiracy theories, referring to a study by Dr Ramit Debnath which I assume is this (graphical abstract below).
My very brief reading of this these is using token analysis, particularly the occurrence of "#chemtrails" as a label for conspiracy theories.  The BBC at least imply that this indicates that some opposition to solar radiation management via stratospheric aerosol injection is driven by irrational belief in current government sponsored mind control, rather than the rational arguments against this technology.
From a technical standpoint, would solar radiation management via stratospheric aerosol injection be considered a form of "chemtrail"?


No, because chemtrail is not a technical concept, and I think you would have difficulty to define it. If it is ok for you... call how do you want, but do not use chemtrail in technical context, it would be silly
